VQA v2.0 Dataset: more than 40000 images are missing
I'm working on training a model on VQA v2.0 dataset. The dataset can be found at https://visualqa.org/download.html
I installed the zip files containing image data (all splits) under the section balanced real images. Upon extracting images from these zip files, I noticed inconsistency in the number of images on the website and the one I had obtained after extraction.
Training Images: Expected 82,783 vs. Actual 41,635
Validation Images: Expected 40,504 vs. Actual 40,493 (close match)
Testing Images: Expected 81,434 vs. Actual 41,915
Btw, I'm assuming that the numbers provided on the website are accurate.
I got the actual number of images from the bottom left corner in the file explorer (I'm using Windows 11).
I'm unsure about the nature of this problem; I didn't receive any error while installing or extracting the zip files, so I don't think there is an issue with file extraction. Is it possible if there is some corrupted data in the file which I might not be aware of? Or maybe the file explorer isn't giving an accurate number (is this possible?). I want to confirm if anyone has faced such an issue before with this dataset, or in general while downloading a huge dataset of images locally
I tried finding if someone had a similar query online, couldn't find one. So I asked ChatGPT regarding the issue, wasn't really helpful tho.
